# Xamarin C# Android - converting .3gpp audio to bytes & sending to parseObject

Tags: c#, android, parsing, audio, xamarin

I'm pretty new to processing recorded sound.
I can successfully record audio into a .3gpp file, save it locally on my mobile device, and play it back.

The trouble I'm having is that I want to convert the sound file into binary so that I can stick it into a parseObject, and upload the file to a cloud. I then want to be able to access that file from a separate device, and stream it.

--UPDATE--- I'm not using binary anymore, I'm using a parseFile object. I now just need to pull the object down from the cloud.

Here's the code I'm using to record the audio (working):

```
string sName;
string path = "/storage/extSdCard/";
string newPath = "";


_start.Click += delegate {
    _stop.Enabled = !_stop.Enabled;
    _start.Enabled = !_start.Enabled;
    sName = _edittext.Text;

    if (sName.Equals(" "))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        //user enters a name for ther audio file
        newPath = path + sName + ".3gpp";
        _recorder.SetAudioSource (AudioSource.Mic);      
        _recorder.SetOutputFormat (OutputFormat.ThreeGpp);            
        _recorder.SetAudioEncoder (AudioEncoder.AmrNb);           
        _recorder.SetOutputFile (newPath);
        _recorder.Prepare ();               
        _recorder.Start ();

    }

};

_stop.Click += delegate {
    _stop.Enabled = !_stop.Enabled;

    _recorder.Stop ();
    //  _recorder.Reset ();

    _player.SetDataSource (newPath);
    _player.Prepare ();
    _player.Start ();
};
```

Here is the class I'm using to send the data to a cloud - this is executed on the click of a button and works, it currently sends hard coded strings into an object which i can successfully retrieve.
HOWEVER, I want the binary string to go into the testObject["audio"], so I can retrieve it.

```
async Task sendToCloud()
{

    ParseClient.Initialize ("--I've put my keys here but I'm censoring them--", "--I've put my keys here but I'm censoring them--");

try
        {

            byte[] data =null;
            ParseFile file = null;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(LoadPath))
            {
                data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
                file = new ParseFile("theaudio.3gpp", data);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Awaiting reader");
            await file.SaveAsync ();

            var auidoParseObject = new ParseObject("AudioWithData");
            //Console.WriteLine(ParseUser.getUserName());
            auidoParseObject["userName"] = "userName";
            auidoParseObject["file"] = file;
            await auidoParseObject.SaveAsync();
}
```

Any help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED.

---

EDIT2:
I've made some progress, I'm struggling, however, to get the audio file down from the cloud still.
here's my new code:
    async Task sendToCloud(string filename)
        {

```
        ParseClient.Initialize ("censored", "censored");

        var testObject = new ParseObject ("Audio");

        string LoadPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string savetheFile = sName + ".3gpp";
        string tempUserName;
        LoadPath += savetheFile;
        Console.WriteLine ("loadPath:  " + LoadPath);
        try
        {

            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(LoadPath);
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile(savetheFile, data);
            await file.SaveAsync();

            var auidoParseObject = new ParseObject("AudioWithData");
            //Console.WriteLine(ParseUser.getUserName());
            if (ParseUser.CurrentUser != null)
            {
                tempUserName = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username.ToString();
            }

            else{
                tempUserName = "Anonymous";
            }
            //tempUserName = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("PARSE USERNAME: " + tempUserName);

                auidoParseObject["userName"] = tempUserName;


            auidoParseObject["userName"] = tempUserName;
            auidoParseObject["file"] = file;
            await auidoParseObject.SaveAsync();

        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to await audio object! {0}" + e);
        }

    }
```

So currently, my objects have the following structure:
"auidoParseObject" contains two children: username (string) and file (ParseFile object)
"file" has two children: the name of the audio (entered by the user -string), and the data in bytes.

I need the audio to be placed into a mdeiaplayer player object, and played.

In the long run, I'll want to extract:
(forgive my pseudo-SQL, but I don't understand the querying documentation):

Select (all files) from (audioParseObject) where (the username = current user.username)

AND THEN
put those files into a listview

user selects a file from the listview and it plays.

ANY help or pointers would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse has really good [docs](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#files) on their site with examples - have you read them?

First, you would use a ParseFile (not a ParseObject) to save your file

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path_to_your_file);
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("your_file_name_and_ext", data);
await file.SaveAsync();
```

After you save your file, you can add a reference to it in your ParseObject

```
testObject ["audio"] = file;
```

To retrieve the file later, you use the Url property from the ParseFile.

```
var file = testObject.Get<ParseFile>("audio");
byte[] data = await new HttpClient().GetByteArrayAsync(file.Url);
```

Comment: Jason, Thanks a lot for this, I had read all of the documentation on ParseObjects before making this post, shortly after making the post, I saw the ParseFile documentation. The issue I now have is that I can't pull the file down on the other side. I'll amend y code example to show you how it's working, if you could help in retrieving the file, that'd be great!

Comment: don't use System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes on binary data.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks alot for the advice, I've moved it on further, and I can now lookup the sound on parse's data store and play it successfully through my computer. I'm struggling however, to play it through the handset on a button click that I've set up... I've updated the new code under EDIT2  above. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything in your edit about downloading the file - have you tried the code in my last suggestion?  If so, what specific problem are you having?  Since your original question was about saving a binary file to Parse, it might be better to close this question and create a new one dealing with retrieving and playing the file.

Comment: I've made a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316475/xamarin-c-sharp-android-and-parse-downloading-a-parsefile-inside-a-parseobject

Comment: Done! Sorry Jason, I forgot to do that, it was VERY helpful, thanks!