# Xamarin C# android and PARSE - Downloading a parseFile inside a parseObject

Tags: c#, android, audio, parse-platform, xamarin

I previously made a post asking how to send a .3gpp audio file up to the parse cloud here: 
[Xamarin C# Android - converting .3gpp audio to bytes & sending to parseObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259432/xamarin-c-sharp-android-converting-3gpp-audio-to-bytes-sending-to-parseobje)

I have managed to do this successfully, on parse's data manager, I can click the file's link and play the sound sent from my android device successfully.
Here's the code for uploading the data to the cloud:

```
async Task sendToCloud(string filename)
    {

        ParseClient.Initialize ("Censored Key", "Censored Key");
        string LoadPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string savetheFile = sName + ".3gpp";
        string tempUserName;
        LoadPath += savetheFile;
        Console.WriteLine ("loadPath:  " + LoadPath);
        try
        {

            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(LoadPath);
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile(savetheFile, data);
            await file.SaveAsync();

            var auidoParseObject = new ParseObject("AudioWithData");
            //Console.WriteLine(ParseUser.getUserName());
            if (ParseUser.CurrentUser != null)
            {
                tempUserName = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username.ToString();
            }

            else{
                tempUserName = "Anonymous";
            }
            //tempUserName = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("PARSE USERNAME: " + tempUserName);

                auidoParseObject["userName"] = tempUserName;


            auidoParseObject["userName"] = tempUserName;
            auidoParseObject["file"] = file;
            await auidoParseObject.SaveAsync();

        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to await audio object! {0}" + e);
        }

    }
```

So as you can see, I'm sending a ParseObject called "AudioWithData".
This object contains two children: 
-The username of the user who uploaded the file (string)
-The parseFile called "file" (which has the following two children)
---SaveTheFile (A string containing the name of the audio file, input by the user, with the .3gpp extension added on the end, for example "myAudioFile.3gpp"
---data (this contains the bytes of the audio file)

I need to be able to download the file onto my android device, and play it through a mediaplayer object.

I've checked over the documentation on the parse website, but I haven't managed to do this:
(excuse my pseudo querying syntax here)
SELECT (audio files)  FROM (the parseObject) WHERE (the username = current user)
I then, eventually, want to place all of these files into a listview, and when the user clicks the file, it plays the audio.

I've tried the following but I don't really know what I'm doing with it...

```
async Task RetrieveSound(string filename)
    {
        ParseClient.Initialize ("Censored key", "Censored key");
        Console.WriteLine ("Hit RetrieveSound, filename = " + filename);
        string username;
        var auidoParseObject = new ParseObject("AudioWithData");
        if (ParseUser.CurrentUser != null) {
            username = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username.ToString ();
        } else {
            username = "Anonymous";
        }
        string cloudFileName;
        Console.WriteLine ("username set to: " + username);


        var HoldThefile = auidoParseObject.Get<ParseFile>("audio");

        //fgher
        var query = from audioParseObject in ParseObject.GetQuery("userName")
                where audioParseObject.Get<String>("userName") == username
            select file;
        IEnumerable<ParseFile> results = await query.FindAsync();

        Console.WriteLine ("passed the query");
        //wfojh

        byte[] data = await new HttpClient().GetByteArrayAsync(results.Url);
        Console.WriteLine ("putting in player...");
        _player.SetDataSourceAsync (data);
        _player.Prepare;
        _player.Start (); 
}
```

Any help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED! Even a point in the right direction would be great!
Thanks!

EDIT--

I'm actually getting a query error on the following lines
(I can't post images because of my reputation - I lost access to my main stackOverflow account :/  )
Links to images here:

first error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZBJr.png
  second error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkHvX.png
Any ideas? The parse documentation is vague about this.

Answer (score 0):

this line will return a collection of results

```
IEnumerable<ParseFile> results = await query.FindAsync();
```

you either need to iterate through them with `foreach`, or just pick the first one

```
// for testing, just pick the first one
if (results.Count > 0) {

  var result = results[0];

  byte[] data = await new HttpClient().GetByteArrayAsync(result.Url);

  File.WriteAllBytes(some_path_to_a_temp_file, data);

  // at this point, you can just initialize your player with the audio file path and play as normal

}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try when get to my laptop. Thanks

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the response, however I'm actually getting an error with the query itself, please see my edit at the bottom of my original post. I've snapshotted the errors into images, however, I can't directly post images on here due to my reputation points.